# How do I control the background color during the iPhone flip view animation transition?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have some pretty standard flipping action going on:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"swapScreens" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

To Apple's credit, this style of animation is amazingly easy to work with.  Very cool, and I've been able to animate transitions, flips, fades etc. throughout the app very easily.

**Question**: During the flip transition, the background visible 'behind' the two views during the flip is white and I'd like it to be black.  I've:

- Set the background of the containing view (`self.view` above) - no dice.  I really thought that would work.
- Set the background of each view to black - no dice.  I didn't think this would work although you give different things a shot to understand better :)
- Google'd like crazy; keep landing on Safari-related listings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a color or an image. You can add a view to do it:

```
UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[window addSubView:bgView];
```

Or set the background color on the window directly:

```
[[appDelegate window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: I'm partially wrong.  Digging in to xcode, there actually is a backgroundColor property on UIWindow.  You can skip the UIView step.  Just do  
    [[appDelegate window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

Comment: Or just do it in ApplicationDidFinishLanuching:  with a simple window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Comment: i am still getting the white color.

Comment: It might be the navigation controllers view that needs the background colour changed if using one of those.

Answer (score 6):

You can also set the background color on the Window in MainWindow.xib in IB if that's easier.