# How do I set the page curl bottom side background color/image during the transition animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I'm transitioning between views in my application using a `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` transition animation. However the standard white background of the bottom side of the page curl looks ugly in my application.  How do I change the background color (or image) of the 'page' backside?

I've tried without success the suggestions posted on these two pages:

[How do I control the background color during the iPhone flip view animation transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899211/how-do-i-control-the-background-color-during-the-iphone-flip-view-animation-tran)

http://adrianhosey.blogspot.com/2009/04/putting-background-behind-uiview.html

As per the suggestions in the above linked posts I've tried adding a subview to both my view and window by adding the following code to `viewDidLoad:` but this also did not work:

```
UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.window.frame];
dummyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:dummyView];
[self.view.window addSubview:dummyView];
```

For reference, this is my animation code:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp|UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                animations:^{}
                completion:^ (BOOL success){
                   // do some stuff here
                }];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code for animation curl up.....

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                       forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailviewcontyrollerObj animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this in your appDelegate's `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`method:

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

window.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"].CGImage;
```